# Find all occurrences of a regex pattern and replace with eval output

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file which contains a lot of strings such as

```
Chr(101)
Chr(97)
Chr(104)
...
```

I am using the below code to find all occurrences of such strings using regex. What I'd like to do is to replace each occurrence with its evaluated output. So in this case I'd replace the above with:

```
e
a
h
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
with open(oFile, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      # find all occurrences of Chr(\d+\) and put in a list
      chrList = [str(s) for s in re.findall(r'Chr\(\d+\)', line)]
      # print chrList 
      for c in chrList:
        # print eval(c.lower())
        out = re.sub(c, eval(c.lower()), line)
```

If I print the `eval(c.lower())` line then it outputs as expected. However the `re.sub` line fails with the following error:

> ```
> raise error, v # invalid expression sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)
> ```

Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Aside: your `chrList` assignment is overly complex. Prefer: `chrList = re.findall(r'Chr\(\d+\)', line)` Realize that `re.findall` already returns a `list` of `str` objects.

Comment: @Robᵩ good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going to want to escape your search pattern [because parenthesis are special characters in regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). You can easily do this using [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape).

```
out = re.sub(re.escape(c), eval(c.lower()), line)
```

And as an example:

```
strings = ['Chr(100)', 'Chr(101)', 'Chr(102)']
values = [re.sub(re.escape(c), eval(c.lower()), c) for c in strings]

# ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

That being said, why not just use `replace()`?

```
out = line.replace(c, eval(c.lower())
```

Comment: i still get the same error. c is not the pattern but rather an entry in my list after finding each occurrence

Comment: @m0atz How is `c` not the pattern? It's the thing you're trying to match and replace, right?

Comment: I see what you're saying, replace is much better and is one of those 'why didnt i think of that' moments.

Comment: @m0atz based on the code you have posted, you never actually write the output *back* to the file. You will need to read in the file, close it, open it for writing, and write data back out.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use distinct search and replace functions. You can invoke `eval` using the functional form of `re.sub`:

```
for line in f:
  out = re.sub(r'Chr\(\d+\)', lambda c: eval(c.group(0).lower()), line)
  print out
```

Comment: Awesome awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing but without `eval()` or imports:

```
strings = ['Chr(100)', 'Chr(101)', 'Chr(102)']
values = [chr(x) for x in (int(c.replace("Chr(", "").replace(")","")) for c in strings)]
```

Comment: Really like this approach. Thanks